# Position fixed not working inside RoyalSlider gallery

Tags: html, css

I'm using a trick to change text color when it's over other content using `position:fixed` elements inside `position:absolute` elements with the clip attribute.

It's working on other parts of the page but on the image gallery the menu won't stick to the top to the browser window instead it sticks to the top of the parent container even though it has `position:fixed` and `top:0`.

Here's a [link](http://carlosbergen.com/anaelena/) to the page. The gallery appears when you click one of the square images.

And a picture:

[image]

Comment: You want your menu to behave like in second picture?

Comment: No, I want the second menu to be on fixed on the top of the browser window, instead it's fixing to the top of the parent container.